# PhoneGap installation fails with "Missing one of these" error message

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to install the latest PhoneGap version to my Eclipse project, but I'm having an issue, here is the error message I'm getting:

[image]

Though I have all of these! I used [THIS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) to install PhoneGap.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the getting started guide should be more explicit on the other bits you need to setup in order to get the create command to work correctly. I've recently pushed a change to the docs but it hasn't shown up on the docs.phonegap.com site.

What you will need to do is open a command prompt and type:

```
java
```

If that program can not be found in your PATH then you will need to add the $JAVA_HOME\bin directory to the PATH environment variable.

Then type:

```
android
```

If that program can not be found in your PATH then you will need to add $ANDROID_HOME\tools and $ANDROID_HOME\platform_tools to the PATH environment variable.

Then type:

```
ant
```

If that program can not be found in your PATH then you will need to add $ANT_HOME\bin to the PATH environment variable.

Once all those programs can be found in the PATH then create should work for you. Let me know if this helps as I need to make the docs better.

Comment: Finally!! I cant believe I had to waste 2 hours to install this plugin =\ Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Omar, I'm going to make the docs better and add this info.

Comment: All 3 commands work - java/ant/android - yet I still get the missing one of error. Now what?  (android loads the sdk manager, is that supposed to happen?)

Comment: I saw your blog - http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html   I had Java working without using JAVA_HOME var so I needed to make one...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good resource for the whole process: [How to install Phonegap latest for Android](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a start to finish guide I've knocked together, you can run through the steps and see which you have/ haven't done:

- Download/ Install Node.JS
- Download/ Install GIT for windows
- Download/ Install Phonegap by opening NODE.JS command line and typing: `npm install -g phonegap`
- Download/ Install Apache 2.4
- Download/ Install Apache Ant
- Add Variable name: `ANT_HOME` with filepath to User/ System variables
- Add `%ANT_HOME%/bin` to `PATH` under user variables
- Download/ Install JRE ( select applicable version number (if in doubt then most recent)
- Download/ Install JDK (Select applicable version number (if in doubt then most recent)
- Add Variable name: `JAVA_HOME` with filepath to User/ System variables (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`  )
- Add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to PATH under user variables
- Download / Extract Android SDK ( select "download for other platforms" and select version to avoid downloading their bundle
- Add Android SDK Tools folder eg: `C:\android-sdk-windows\tools` to the `PATH` variable
- Add Android SDK Platform tools eg: `C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` to the `PATH` variable

If all the above is done then you're ready to begin the user set up, you'll need to create a new project with Phonegap and create a new emulator through the android Virtual Device Manager.